# Powershell Deployment - Enable-SPFeature Error

Tags: deployment, powershell, feature, feature-receiver

I get the following problem activating a feature in powershell:

```
Enable-SPFeature : The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I can activate the feature just fine through VS (by deploying the solution) as well as the browser.

The feature has feature receiver code. I have another feature (with feature receiver) which activates just fine through Powershell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today when I tried to deploy in my development environment. I tried to retract. But it didn't help. In my case somewhere it failed to remove dll from GAC. So I deleted my dll from GAC (C:\Windows\assembly) and the deploy worked.

By the way, I ran iisreset /noforce before being able to delete the dll file.

Comment: I tried taking the dlls out of GAC but to no avail. I don't know what exactly happened but I came back to work the next day and everything is working fine... One of many SharePoint mysteries...

Comment: :) Fun that it worked. Sharepoint is really a mystery.

Comment: exactly wich dll we're talking about ?

Comment: Your dll, the dll that is deployed through your custom wsp.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I do is close my PowerShell window & open a new instance, this works almost every time. If not I move onto restarting SPTimerv4 & IISreset, retract & deploy. if its still a no go I rebuild my package and manually remove the existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `restart-service SPTimerV4` before you do your solution add/deploy and feature activation.  This [article](http://sisharepoint.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/getting-around-gac-problems-when-you-deploy-sharepoint-solutions-with-powershell/) by Bjørn Stærk describes the problem and the solution.